# Passing data thru a Swift segue works every other time

Tags: swift

I have a tableview which reads and RSS feed of episodic radio shows. I want the playlist for the selected show to pass to a second controller for viewing in a textview when a cell is selected. I am using a segue and it works when I select the same cell twice (every other time). I have searched everywhere without success and its driving me nuts! Please help. Here is my code

```
     // Only grab the data at the selected cell
        //
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Load the variable to hold whats in the row
        currentList = feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("itunes:summary") as NSString

        // Load the row number
        myRow = (indexPath.row)

    }

    // Pass the data thru the segue
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {

//            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController
//            vc.toPass = currentList
//            println(vc.toPass)



            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            vc.toPass = currentList
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my second view controller

```
 import UIKit

class secondViewController: UIViewController {

    // Create a property to accept the data

    @IBOutlet weak var textPlayList: UITextView!



    // Create a variable to store the data

    var toPass:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        textPlayList.text = toPass
        textPlayList.textColor = UIColor .whiteColor()
        textPlayList.font = UIFont .boldSystemFontOfSize(10)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prepareForSegue` happens before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so your `currentList` variable is set up too late for be useful in `prepareForSegue`.

To fix this, move this code:

```
    // Load the variable to hold whats in the row
    currentList = feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("itunes:summary") as NSString
```

to `prepareForSegue`:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let currentList = feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("itunes:summary") as NSString
                vc.toPass = currentList
            }
        }
    }
```

In general, you don't need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if you are using segues because `prepareForSegue` is where you set up the transition.

Comment: I have tried that but get the error:  Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath' when I place this assignment in prepareForSegue

Comment: See updated answer.  You need to call `indexPathForSelectedRow` to get the  `indexPath`.

Comment: Did exactly that and get : (UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathForSelectedRow'. Did something changed in swift ?

Comment: That sounds really odd.  I suggest you post your table view controller code as a new question.

Comment: Got it while typing my new question: I was using a tableview, and not a tableview controller, thus I had to replace "self" by the table name :)