# Detail View UITableView - Pass data before segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue

So in my storyboard file I have a segue from one UITableViewController going to another so that when the user taps the cell it opens the next table. Nothing special. But when they tap the cell I need to specify the data being loaded into the next view. I do this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Depending on the indexPath.row I set the value of a variable that is assigned to the detail Table view in the prepareForSegue function. I have the view controller loaded as a variable in `let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController`. From here is set the data with an assignment function. However, when I tap the table the data does not show up until I press back and tap it again. Basically the data is being assigned *after* the segue... How can I assign the data and perform the segue afterwards?

EDIT

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoOne;
            break
        case 1:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoTwo;
            break
        case 2:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoThree;
            break
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController
        let destinationTitle = "Detail View"
        detailViewController.title = destinationTitle
        self.passedScores.sort{$0 > $1};
        detailViewController.setData(self.passedInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846804/passing-data-thru-a-swift-segue-works-every-other-time

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `prepareForSegue` function to pass data to the target view controller before the controller is displayed. Here is a great article on how to do this in Swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18471

Answer (score 1):

Just use prepareForSegue for this task

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

 if segue.identifier == "mysegue" {
  let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailTableViewController
  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoOne;
            break
        case 1:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoTwo;
            break
        case 2:
            self.passedInfo = self.infoThree;
                break
        default:
            break;
    }
    vc.setData(self.passedInfo);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'd take a look at the sender, too. Odds are it's the selected table cell (or possibly a subview). If so, you can get the index path from the cell and be a bit less elbowy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to a variable in didSelectRowatIndexPath, check the selected row inside your prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was control dragging from the cell in the tableview instead of from the view controller itself. It worked correctly when I moved the segue and manually call it from didSelectRowatIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. This will set the variable first and then call the segue. Here is how:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        self.passedInfo = self.infoOne;
        break
    case 1:
        self.passedInfo = self.infoTwo;
        break
    case 2:
        self.passedInfo = self.infoThree;
        break
    default:
        break;
    }

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowInfo", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier = "ShowInfo" {
    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController
    let destinationTitle = "Detail View"
    detailViewController.title = destinationTitle
    self.passedScores.sort{$0 > $1};
    detailViewController.setData(self.passedInfo);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you provide the identifier to your segue in your storyboard.

Hope this helps. :)